# Transition group animation changes behaviour when adding 3rd element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, transition

**Context**: I have a `div` on the top of the page that I show / hide from a button. The `div` is under the button and above the content. I've used `transition-group` so that the rest of the content slides up/down over the `div` when it shows/hides. The content has a `margin-top` so that it limits itself from the above `div` that shows/hides.

**Need**: I want a margin on top of the `div` so that when it's shown, it retains space between itself and the button.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uPJm.jpg

**Problems**: I've tried 2 ways:

1) **Placing a margin-top to the hiding `div`.**
Because I have `position:absolute` on the `div` when hiding it so that the content gets over the `div`, the `div` resizes to the size of the content, and so the margin gets automatically smaller; so when hiding it, the margin gets smaller before it hides, and it's ugly.
**GIF**: https://gph.is/2QInDfj

2) **Adding an `hr` above the `div`, inside the `transition-group`.** Without the `hr`, the slide works just as intended, over the `div`. But when I add the `hr` and click to hide the `div`, the slide happens just as intended but the `div` and `hr` disappear instantly, instead of it showing and the content sliding over it and covering it.
**GIF**: https://gph.is/2yd4JGt

**Desired visual effect** without the margin/hr on top:
https://gph.is/2OPZyFV

**HTML**

```
<transition-group name="slide">
    <hr class="m-0" v-if="isVisible" key='h'>
    <div class="d-flex" v-if="isVisible" id="filters" key='x'>
        <div class="pl-5">
            <p class="filterTitles">Day</p>
            <app-day-filter v-for="day in weekDay" 
                :key="day.index" 
                :day="day">
            </app-day-filter>
        </div>
        <div class="pl-5">
            <p class="filterTitles">Time of day</p>
            <app-tod-filter v-for="todf in tod" 
                :key="tod.index" 
                :todf="todf">
            </app-tod-filter>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-event v-for='(eveniment, index) in filterEvent' 
        :key='index' 
        :eveniment='eveniment' 
        :index='index'></app-event>
</transition-group>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-enter {
    opacity:0;
}
.slide-enter-active {
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.slide-leave-active{
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.slide-move {
    transition: transform 1s;
}
#filters {
/* border-top: 1px solid lightgrey; */
}
```

Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily a CSS concern.

If the `hr` element is introduced into the layout within the `transition-group`, and, the `transition` CSS property is concerned with `all`, *and*, `position` is being set to `absolute` during the `leave-active` state (which will cause the element to "disappear" from its previous, relative position in the layout flow), then numerous elements and properties are going to be transitioned simultaneously, resulting in undesired effects.

However, given that the question seeks a solution *without* the `margin` and `hr` on top of the `transition-group`, and assuming the button has an event handler, like this:

```
<button class="filter-button" v-on:click="toggleSlider">Filters</button>
```

The function `toggleSlider` will toggle the `isVisible` property that the animated transition depends upon:

```
methods: {
  toggleSlider() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }
}
```

And with CSS, instead of transitioning `all`, merely transition the properties that will achieve the sought after effect, namely, `opacity`, and with this answer, `max-height`. By removing the absolute positioning altogether, and using relative position plus z-indexing with the following CSS, the desired effect is achieved.

```
/* put margin spacing on the bottom of the button */
.filter-button {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* add relative positioning to enforce z-indexing */
.filter-group {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* add relative positioning to enforce z-indexing */
.filter-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* hidden states */
.slide-enter,
.slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
}

/* shown states - max-height can be adjusted as desired */
.slide-enter-to,
.slide-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 300px;
}

/* while animating during animation entry phase */
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in, max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

/* while animating during the animation departure phase */
.slide-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.75s ease-out, max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

/* add padding to bottom of filters section */
.pl-5 {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

By adding margin to the bottom of the button and the filter section, the spacing between sections is preserved.

I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/946xxvn4zw) to illustrate this solution.